# Error in ans[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions while running a linear model

Tags: r, model, gamlss

I am doing a GAMLSS model, this linear model could do iterations automatically until it could get a best combinations of explanatory variables. After I put some explanatory variables in the model, it was still good in iteration process at first several rounds, then I got a Error like this.

```
Model with term  Spr_Tmean has failed 
Model with term  Spr_Psum has failed 
Model with term  Spr_sdmean has failed 
Model with term  Spr_Wsum has failed 
Model with term  Sum_Tmean has failed 
Model with term  Sum_Psum has failed 
Model with term  Sum_sdmean has failed 
Model with term  Sum_Wsum has failed 
Error in ans[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I also checked some questions related to Error in xxx[,1]: incorrect number of dimensions, but i think this is not what i want.

I also list the source function in here, you could search "ans[, 1]" to locate the problem. What "ans[, 1]" means in here? I am not professional to check this function, so any answer about the reason caused this Error, and how to solve this problem would be welcome. Thank you in advance.

```
> stepGAICAll.B
function (object, scope, direction = c("both", "backward", 
    "forward"), trace = T, keep = NULL, steps = 1000, scale = 0, 
    k = 2, parallel = c("no", "multicore", "snow"), 
    ncpus = 1L, cl = NULL, ...) 
{
    mydeviance <- function(x, ...) {
        dev <- deviance(x)
        if (!is.null(dev)) 
            dev
        else extractAIC(x, k = 0)[2]
    }
    cut.string <- function(string) {
        if (length(string) > 1) 
            string[-1] <- paste("\n", string[-1], sep = "")
        string
    }
    re.arrange <- function(keep) {
        namr <- names(k1 <- keep[[1]])
        namc <- names(keep)
        nc <- length(keep)
        nr <- length(k1)
        array(unlist(keep, recursive = FALSE), c(nr, nc), list(namr, 
            namc))
    }
    step.results <- function(models, fit, object, usingCp = FALSE) {
        change <- sapply(models, "[[", "change")
        rd <- sapply(models, "[[", "deviance")
        dd <- c(NA, abs(diff(rd)))
        rdf <- sapply(models, "[[", "df.resid")
        ddf <- c(NA, abs(diff(rdf)))
        AIC <- sapply(models, "[[", "AIC")
        heading <- c("Stepwise Model Path \nAnalysis of Deviance Table", 
            "\nInitial  Model:", deparse(as.vector(formula(object))), 
            "\nFinal   Model:", deparse(as.vector(formula(fit))), 
            "\n")
        aod <- if (usingCp) 
            data.frame(Step = change, Df = ddf, Deviance = dd, 
                `Resid. Df` = rdf, `Resid. Dev` = rd, 
                Cp = AIC, check.names = FALSE)
        else data.frame(Step = change, Df = ddf, Deviance = dd, 
            `Resid. Df` = rdf, `Resid. Dev` = rd, 
            AIC = AIC, check.names = FALSE)
        attr(aod, "heading") <- heading
        class(aod) <- c("Anova", "data.frame")
        fit$anova <- aod
        fit
    }
    droptermAllP <- function(object, scope, test = c("Chisq", 
        "none"), k = 2, sorted = FALSE, trace = FALSE, 
        parallel = c("no", "multicore", "snow"), 
        ncpus = 1L, cl = NULL, ...) {
        drop1.scope <- function(terms1, terms2) {
            terms1 <- terms(terms1, "mu")
            f2 <- if (missing(terms2)) 
                numeric(0)
            else attr(terms(terms2, "mu"), "factor")
            factor.scope(attr(terms1, "factor"), list(drop = f2))$drop
        }
        safe_pchisq <- function(q, df, ...) {
            df[df <= 0] <- NA
            pchisq(q = q, df = df, ...)
        }
        tl <- attr(terms(object, "mu"), "term.labels")
        if (missing(scope)) {
            scope <- drop1.scope(object)
        }
        else {
            if (!is.character(scope)) 
                scope <- attr(terms(update.formula(formula(object, 
                  "mu"), scope), "mu"), "term.labels")
            if (!all(match(scope, tl, FALSE))) 
                stop("scope is not a subset of term labels")
        }
        ns <- length(scope)
        ans <- matrix(nrow = ns + 1, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(c("<none>", 
            scope), c("df", "AIC")))
        ans[1, ] <- extractAIC(object, scale, k = k, ...)
        fn <- function(term) {
            if (trace) 
                cat("trying -", term, "\n")
            nfit <- update(object, as.formula(paste("~ . -", 
                term)), what = "All", evaluate = FALSE, 
                trace = FALSE)
            nfit <- try(eval.parent(nfit), silent = TRUE)
            if (any(class(nfit) %in% "try-error")) {
                cat("Model with term ", term, "has failed \n")
                NA
            }
            else extractAIC(nfit, scale, k = k, ...)
        }
        ans[-1, ] <- if (ncpus > 1L && (have_mc || have_snow)) {
            if (have_mc) {
                matrix(unlist(parallel::mclapply(scope, fn, mc.cores = ncpus)), 
                  ncol = 2, byrow = T)
            }
            else if (have_snow) {
                list(...)
                if (is.null(cl)) {
                  res <- t(parallel::parSapply(cl, scope, fn))
                  res
                }
                else t(parallel::parSapply(cl, scope, fn))
            }
        }
        else t(sapply(scope, fn))
        dfs <- ans[1, 1] - ans[, 1]
        dfs[1] <- NA
        aod <- data.frame(Df = dfs, AIC = ans[, 2])
        o <- if (sorted) 
            order(aod$AIC)
        else seq(along = aod$AIC)
        test <- match.arg(test)
        if (test == "Chisq") {
            dev <- ans[, 2] - k * ans[, 1]
            dev <- dev - dev[1]
            dev[1] <- NA
            nas <- !is.na(dev)
            P <- dev
            P[nas] <- safe_pchisq(dev[nas], dfs[nas], lower.tail = FALSE)
            aod[, c("LRT", "Pr(Chi)")] <- list(dev, 
                P)
        }
        aod <- aod[o, ]
        head <- c("Single term deletions", "\nModel:", 
            deparse(as.vector(formula(object))))
        class(aod) <- c("anova", "data.frame")
        attr(aod, "heading") <- head
        aod
    }
    addtermAllP <- function(object, scope, test = c("Chisq", 
        "none"), k = 2, sorted = FALSE, trace = FALSE, 
        parallel = c("no", "multicore", "snow"), 
        ncpus = 1L, cl = NULL, ...) {
        add.scope <- function(terms1, terms2) {
            terms1 <- terms(terms1)
            terms2 <- terms(terms2)
            factor.scope(attr(terms1, "factor"), list(add = attr(terms2, 
                "factor")))$add
        }
        safe_pchisq <- function(q, df, ...) {
            df[df <= 0] <- NA
            pchisq(q = q, df = df, ...)
        }
        if (missing(scope) || is.null(scope)) 
            stop("no terms in scope")
        if (!is.character(scope)) 
            scope <- add.scope(object, terms(update.formula(formula(object, 
                "mu"), scope)))
        if (!length(scope)) 
            stop("no terms in scope for adding to object")
        ns <- length(scope)
        ans <- matrix(nrow = ns + 1, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(c("<none>", 
            scope), c("df", "AIC")))
        ans[1, ] <- extractAIC(object, scale, k = k, ...)
        fn <- function(term) {
            if (trace) 
                cat("trying -", term, "\n")
            nfit <- update(object, as.formula(paste("~ . +", 
                term)), what = "All", trace = FALSE, evaluate = FALSE)
            nfit <- try(eval.parent(nfit), silent = TRUE)
            if (any(class(nfit) %in% "try-error")) {
                cat("Model with term ", term, "has failed \n")
                NA
            }
            else extractAIC(nfit, scale, k = k, ...)
        }
        ans[-1, ] <- if (ncpus > 1L && (have_mc || have_snow)) {
            if (have_mc) {
                matrix(unlist(parallel::mclapply(scope, fn, mc.cores = ncpus)), 
                  ncol = 2, byrow = T)
            }
            else if (have_snow) {
                list(...)
                if (is.null(cl)) {
                  res <- t(parallel::parSapply(cl, scope, fn))
                  res
                }
                else t(parallel::parSapply(cl, scope, fn))
            }
        }
        else t(sapply(scope, fn))
        dfs <- ans[, 1] - ans[1, 1]
        dfs[1] <- NA
        aod <- data.frame(Df = dfs, AIC = ans[, 2])
        o <- if (sorted) 
            order(aod$AIC)
        else seq(along = aod$AIC)
        test <- match.arg(test)
        if (test == "Chisq") {
            dev <- ans[, 2] - k * ans[, 1]
            dev <- dev[1] - dev
            dev[1] <- NA
            nas <- !is.na(dev)
            P <- dev
            P[nas] <- safe_pchisq(dev[nas], dfs[nas], lower.tail = FALSE)
            aod[, c("LRT", "Pr(Chi)")] <- list(dev, 
                P)
        }
        aod <- aod[o, ]
        head <- c("Single term additions for", "\nModel:", 
            deparse(as.vector(formula(object))))
        class(aod) <- c("anova", "data.frame")
        attr(aod, "heading") <- head
        aod
    }
    if (missing(parallel)) 
        parallel <- "no"
    parallel <- match.arg(parallel)
    have_mc <- have_snow <- FALSE
    if (parallel != "no" && ncpus > 1L) {
        if (parallel == "multicore") 
            have_mc <- .Platform$OS.type != "windows"
        else if (parallel == "snow") 
            have_snow <- TRUE
        if (!have_mc && !have_snow) 
            ncpus <- 1L
        loadNamespace("parallel")
    }
    if (have_snow) {
        cl <- parallel::makeForkCluster(ncpus)
        if (RNGkind()[1L] == "L'Ecuyer-CMRG") 
            parallel::clusterSetRNGStream(cl)
        on.exit(parallel::stopCluster(cl))
    }
    Terms <- terms(object)
    object$formula <- Terms
    object$call$formula <- Terms
    md <- missing(direction)
    direction <- match.arg(direction)
    backward <- direction == "both" | direction == "backward"
    forward <- direction == "both" | direction == "forward"
    if (missing(scope)) {
        fdrop <- numeric(0)
        fadd <- attr(Terms, "factors")
        if (md) 
            forward <- FALSE
    }
    else {
        if (is.list(scope)) {
            fdrop <- if (!is.null(fdrop <- scope$lower)) 
                attr(terms(update.formula(formula(object, what = "mu"), 
                  fdrop), what = "mu"), "factors")
            else numeric(0)
            fadd <- if (!is.null(fadd <- scope$upper)) 
                attr(terms(update.formula(formula(object, what = "mu"), 
                  fadd), what = "mu"), "factors")
        }
        else {
            fadd <- if (!is.null(fadd <- scope)) 
                attr(terms(update.formula(formula(object, what = "mu"), 
                  scope), what = "mu"), "factors")
            fdrop <- numeric(0)
        }
    }
    models <- vector("list", steps)
    if (!is.null(keep)) 
        keep.list <- vector("list", steps)
    if (is.list(object) && (nmm <- match("nobs", names(object), 
        0)) > 0) 
        n <- object[[nmm]]
    else n <- length(residuals(object))
    fit <- object
    bAIC <- extractAIC(fit, scale, k = k, ...)
    edf <- bAIC[1]
    bAIC <- bAIC[2]
    if (is.na(bAIC)) 
        stop("AIC is not defined for this model, so stepAIC cannot proceed")
    nm <- 1
    Terms <- terms(fit, "mu")
    if (trace) 
        cat("Start:  AIC=", format(round(bAIC, 2)), "\n", 
            cut.string(deparse(as.vector(formula(fit, what = "mu")))), 
            "\n\n")
    models[[nm]] <- list(deviance = mydeviance(fit), df.resid = n - 
        edf, change = "", AIC = bAIC)
    if (!is.null(keep)) 
        keep.list[[nm]] <- keep(fit, bAIC)
    usingCp <- FALSE
    while (steps > 0) {
        steps <- steps - 1
        AIC <- bAIC
        ffac <- attr(Terms, "factors")
        if (!is.null(sp <- attr(Terms, "specials")) && 
            !is.null(st <- sp$strata)) 
            ffac <- ffac[-st, ]
        scope <- factor.scope(ffac, list(add = fadd, drop = fdrop))
        aod <- NULL
        change <- NULL
        if (backward && length(scope$drop)) {
            aod <- droptermAllP(fit, scope$drop, trace = max(0, 
                trace - 1), k = k, test = "none", parallel = parallel, 
                ncpus = ncpus, cl = cl)
            rn <- row.names(aod)
            row.names(aod) <- c(rn[1], paste("-", rn[-1], 
                sep = " "))
            if (any(aod$Df == 0, na.rm = TRUE)) {
                zdf <- aod$Df == 0 & !is.na(aod$Df)
                nc <- match(c("Cp", "AIC"), names(aod))
                nc <- nc[!is.na(nc)][1]
                ch <- abs(aod[zdf, nc] - aod[1, nc]) > 0.01
                if (any(ch)) {
                  warning("0 df terms are changing AIC")
                  zdf <- zdf[!ch]
                }
                if (length(zdf) > 0) 
                  change <- rev(rownames(aod)[zdf])[1]
            }
        }
        if (is.null(change)) {
            if (forward && length(scope$add)) {
                aodf <- addtermAllP(fit, scope$add, trace = max(0, 
                  trace - 1), k = k, test = "none", parallel = parallel, 
                  ncpus = ncpus, cl = cl)
                rn <- row.names(aodf)
                row.names(aodf) <- c(rn[1], paste("+", 
                  rn[-1], sep = " "))
                aod <- if (is.null(aod)) 
                  aodf
                else rbind(aod, aodf[-1, , drop = FALSE])
            }
            attr(aod, "heading") <- NULL
            if (is.null(aod) || ncol(aod) == 0) 
                break
            nzdf <- if (!is.null(aod$Df)) 
                aod$Df != 0 | is.na(aod$Df)
            aod <- aod[nzdf, ]
            if (is.null(aod) || ncol(aod) == 0) 
                break
            nc <- match(c("Cp", "AIC"), names(aod))
            nc <- nc[!is.na(nc)][1]
            o <- order(aod[, nc])
            if (trace) 
                print(aod[o, ])
            if (o[1] == 1) 
                break
            change <- rownames(aod)[o[1]]
        }
        usingCp <- match("Cp", names(aod), 0) > 0
        fit <- update(fit, paste("~ .", change), evaluate = FALSE, 
            what = "All", trace = FALSE)
        fit <- eval.parent(fit)
        if (is.list(fit) && (nmm <- match("nobs", names(fit), 
            0)) > 0) 
            nnew <- fit[[nmm]]
        else nnew <- length(residuals(fit))
        if (nnew != n) 
            stop("number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?")
        Terms <- terms(fit, "mu")
        bAIC <- extractAIC(fit, scale, k = k, ...)
        edf <- bAIC[1]
        bAIC <- bAIC[2]
        if (trace) 
            cat("\nStep:  AIC=", format(round(bAIC, 2)), 
                "\n", cut.string(deparse(as.vector(formula(fit, 
                  "mu")))), "\n\n")
        if (bAIC >= AIC + 1e-07) 
            break
        nm <- nm + 1
        models[[nm]] <- list(deviance = mydeviance(fit), df.resid = n - 
            edf, change = change, AIC = bAIC)
        if (!is.null(keep)) 
            keep.list[[nm]] <- keep(fit, bAIC)
    }
    if (!is.null(keep)) 
        fit$keep <- re.arrange(keep.list[seq(nm)])
    step.results(models = models[seq(nm)], fit, object, usingCp)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000026ddc5c40e8>
<environment: namespace:gamlss>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your problem, but I prefer using
stepGAICAll.A()